# Filtering dates for time series plot using dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to filter my dataset to only have rows from the year 1996-2015 and only the columns orgid,stdate,locid,charnam. The entire dataset contains years from 1988 to 2015 and a great deal of different columns. I just recently learned about the dplyr package and figured this would be the way to go. However I keep getting this error and I don't understand why I'm getting it. The error I keep getting is `Error in is_character(x) : object 'rlang_is_character' not found`

This is my code so far:

```
    ########## download necessary packages to make script run #########################################################################
if (!require(pacman)) {
  install.packages('pacman')

}

pacman::p_load("tidyverse")
#### Read in the necessary data ######
roadsalt_data<-read.table("QADportaldata_1988-2015.tsv",header=T,sep="\t",fill=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Convert date column from a character class to a date class so ggplot can  display as a continuous variable ###
roadsalt_data$stdate <- as.Date(roadsalt_data$stdate)
## Filter dataset to only contain years 1996-2015 ########
roadsalt_data_sub<-roadsalt_data %>%
                     select(orgid,stdate,locid,charnam) %>%
                     filter(between(roadsalt_data, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01")))
```

Heres a preview of the dataset:

```
structure(list(orgid = c("USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", 
"USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ", "USGS-NJ"
), actid = c("nwisnj.01.01300274", "nwisnj.01.01300273", "nwisnj.01.01300247", 
"nwisnj.01.01300242", "nwisnj.01.01300238", "nwisnj.01.01300237", 
"nwisnj.01.01300189", "nwisnj.01.01300189", "nwisnj.01.01300189", 
"nwisnj.01.01300190"), actyp = c("Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine", 
"Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine", 
"Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine", "Sample-Routine"
), stdate = structure(c(15755, 15755, 15748, 15748, 15748, 15748, 
15740, 15740, 15740, 15740), class = "Date"), sttime = c("09:30:00", 
"11:00:00", "10:30:00", "12:00:00", "11:00:00", "11:30:00", "09:25:00", 
"09:25:00", "09:25:00", "09:30:00"), actdep = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_), actdepun = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""
), locid = c("USGS-01407760", "USGS-01445030", "USGS-01380075", 
"USGS-01368820", "USGS-01409815", "USGS-01411400", "USGS-01458570", 
"USGS-01458570", "USGS-01458570", "USGS-01445160"), actcom = c("A-0520044 TPCN = 64mL filtered", 
"A-0520046 TPCN = 124mL filtered", "A-0460036 TPCN = 124mL filtered L-0460036 Received February 14, 2013", 
"A-0460025 TPCN = 125mL filtered L-0460025 Received February 14, 2013", 
"A-0460027 TPCN = 64mL filtered.  ATTN: H.Ardourel, LL ANC and LL pH L-0460027 Received February 14, 2013", 
"A-0460028 TPCN = 125mL filtered. L-0460028 Received February 14, 2013", 
"A-0370012 TPCN = 125mL filtered", "A-0370012 TPCN = 125mL filtered", 
"A-0370012 TPCN = 125mL filtered", "A-0370011 TPCN = 125mL filtered"
), hydcond = c("Stable, normal stage", "Stable, normal stage", 
"Stable, normal stage", "Stable, normal stage", "Stable, high stage", 
"Falling stage", "Stable, normal stage", "Stable, normal stage", 
"Stable, normal stage", "Stable, high stage"), hydev = c("Routine sample", 
"Routine sample", "Routine sample", "Routine sample", "Routine sample", 
"Routine sample", "Routine sample", "Routine sample", "Routine sample", 
"Routine sample"), metcont = c("USGS parameter code 82398", "USGS parameter code 82398", 
"USGS parameter code 82398", "USGS parameter code 82398", "USGS parameter code 82398", 
"USGS parameter code 82398", "USGS parameter code 82398", "USGS parameter code 82398", 
"USGS parameter code 82398", "USGS parameter code 82398"), metnam = c("Multiple verticals", 
"Multiple verticals", "Multiple verticals", "Multiple verticals", 
"Single vertical", "Multiple verticals", "Grab sample  (dip)", 
"Grab sample  (dip)", "Grab sample  (dip)", "Multiple verticals"
), detcond = c("", "", "", "", "Not Detected", "", "", "", "", 
""), charnam = c("Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)", 
"Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)", 
"Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)", 
"Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)", 
"Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)", 
"Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)", 
"Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrite)", "Phosphorus", "Phosphorus", 
"Kjeldahl nitrogen"), samfrac = c("Dissolved", "Dissolved", "Dissolved", 
"Dissolved", "Dissolved", "Dissolved", "Dissolved", "Total", 
"Dissolved", "Dissolved"), val = c("0.84", "1.2", "0.46", "0.28", 
"", "0.66", "3.10", "0.032", "0.028", "0.21"), valunit = c("mg/l", 
"mg/l", "mg/l", "mg/l", "", "mg/l", "mg/l as N", "mg/l as P", 
"mg/l as P", "mg/l as N"), valqual = c("", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), valstat = c("Accepted", "Accepted", "Accepted", 
"Accepted", "Accepted", "Accepted", "Accepted", "Accepted", "Accepted", 
"Accepted"), statcode = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
""), valtype = c("Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", 
"Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual", "Actual"), precval = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), valcom = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "Report level code updated Oct., Nov. 2015. Reference: NWQL Rapi-Note 2011-21 (RLC: IRL => LT-MDL)", 
"", "", ""), valdep = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), 
    valdepun = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), valmetnam = c("Computation by NWIS algorithm", 
    "Computation by NWIS algorithm", "Computation by NWIS algorithm", 
    "Computation by NWIS algorithm", "Computation by NWIS algorithm", 
    "Computation by NWIS algorithm", "NO3+NO2, wf, FCC,NaR, DA", 
    "P, wu, WCA, persulfate CF color", "P, wf, FCA, persulfate CF color", 
    "NH3+org-N, wf, FCA, Kjeldahl, CF"), metdesc = c("NWIS User's Manual, QW System, Section 3.6.7", 
    "NWIS User's Manual, QW System, Section 3.6.7", "NWIS User's Manual, QW System, Section 3.6.7", 
    "NWIS User's Manual, QW System, Section 3.6.7", "NWIS User's Manual, QW System, Section 3.6.7", 
    "NWIS User's Manual, QW System, Section 3.6.7", "", "", "", 
    "USGS OF 00-170"), labcom = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", ""), detlimnam = c("", "", "", "", "Historical Lower Reporting Limit", 
    "", "Long Term Method Detection Level", "Long Term Method Detection Level", 
    "Long Term Method Detection Level", "Long Term Method Detection Level"
    ), detlimval = c("", "", "", "", "0.23", "", "0.04", "0.004", 
    "0.0040", "0.07"), detlimun = c("", "", "", "", "mg/l", "", 
    "mg/l as N", "mg/l as P", "mg/l as P", "mg/l as N"), V63 = c("NWIS", 
    "NWIS", "NWIS", "NWIS", "NWIS", "NWIS", "NWIS", "NWIS", "NWIS", 
    "NWIS")), .Names = c("orgid", "actid", "actyp", "stdate", 
"sttime", "actdep", "actdepun", "locid", "actcom", "hydcond", 
"hydev", "metcont", "metnam", "detcond", "charnam", "samfrac", 
"val", "valunit", "valqual", "valstat", "statcode", "valtype", 
"precval", "valcom", "valdep", "valdepun", "valmetnam", "metdesc", 
"labcom", "detlimnam", "detlimval", "detlimun", "V63"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of `rlang` you have? Try after reinstalling the `rlang` to newer version

Comment: I have version ‘0.2.0.9001’ @akrun

Comment: In the filter step, you are using the whole dataset instead of a column?  Should that be `filter(between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01")))`

Comment: Thanks didn't catch that ! I'm still getting the same error though. @akrun

Comment: Could you please update your post with a dput of a small example i.e. `dput(head(roadsalt_data, 20))` so that we can change whether the error is reproducible.  I think the error is due to the package version

Comment: Sorry new to this.. Is that good? @akrun

Comment: For me, it is working fine `roadsalt_data %>% select(orgid, stdate,locid, charnam) %>% filter(between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01")))`

Comment: Any idea on what I can do? , Since it doesnt seem to be the code. @akrun

Comment: Try doing `roadsalt_data %>% dplyr::select(orgid, stdate, locid, charnam) %>% dplyr::filter(between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01")))`

Comment: Gives me the same error @akrun

Comment: May be, try to resintall the dplyr, rlang packages

Comment: I did. It's still not working... weird! @akrun

Comment: I am using R 3.4.4. with dplyr_0.7.5 and rlang_0.2.0 on linux

Comment: Can you try on a fresh session by not loading `tidyverse`, but just `dplyr` i.e. `library(dplyr)` and then use the code I commented.  I think there is a conflict with the versions of package in tidyverse and the one you installed

Comment: Tried it and it's still giving me the same error. I am using R 3.4.4 with dplyr 0.7.5 and rlang 0.20 as well on windows @akrun

Comment: If you are on windows, why not update to new R version i.e. `R 3.5.0` and update the packages if necessary

Comment: I was unaware that there was a new R version, I will try this. Thanks! @akrun

Comment: I'm not sure I'd recommend upgrading R versions to try and resolve dependency issues, the update to R 3.5.0 is still relatively recent and there are some packages that have had issues getting updated versions released on CRAN for 3.5.0. The compatibility issue is somewhere in the `dplyr` `rlang` toolchain, because when I run @akrun's `dplyr` code with R 3.4.3, dplyr 0.7.4, and rlang 0.2.0.9000 it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup @MattSummersgill !

Comment: I would always install individual packages instead of combo packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `between()` didn't work with `Date`s at one point, even when the `left` and `right` arguments were converted with `as.Date()`.

Here are some alternatives. Since all of your sample data fall between the specified years, these all filter for dates between 2013-02-04 and 2013-02-12. Adjust accordingly.

```r
library(dplyr)

roadsalt_data <- as_tibble(roadsalt_data) # not necessary, just convenient console output 

roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate, locid, charnam) %>%
  filter(stdate >= "2013-02-04", stdate <= "2013-02-12")

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   orgid   stdate     locid         charnam                                
#>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>         <chr>                                  
#> 1 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01380075 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 2 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01368820 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 3 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01409815 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 4 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01411400 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 5 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrit~
#> 6 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 7 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 8 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01445160 Kjeldahl nitrogen

roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate, locid, charnam) %>%
  filter(between(stdate, as.Date("2013-02-04"), as.Date("2013-02-12")))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   orgid   stdate     locid         charnam                                
#>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>         <chr>                                  
#> 1 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01380075 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 2 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01368820 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 3 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01409815 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 4 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01411400 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 5 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrit~
#> 6 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 7 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 8 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01445160 Kjeldahl nitrogen

# How I would've done it
library(lubridate)

roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate, locid, charnam) %>% 
  # filter(between(year(stdate), 1996, 2015)) # for years instead of days
  filter(between(day(stdate), 4, 12))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   orgid   stdate     locid         charnam                                
#>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>         <chr>                                  
#> 1 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01380075 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 2 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01368820 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 3 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01409815 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 4 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01411400 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 5 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrit~
#> 6 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 7 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 8 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01445160 Kjeldahl nitrogen

# If {lubridate} isn't installed, this is all year() and day() do...
get_day <- function(date) as.POSIXlt(date, tz = tz(date))$mday
# get_year <- function(date) as.POSIXlt(date, tz = tz(date))$year + 1900 # for years instead of days

roadsalt_data %>% 
  select(orgid, stdate, locid, charnam) %>%
  # filter(between(get_year(stdate), 1996, 2015)) # for years instead of days
  filter(between(get_day(stdate), 4, 12))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   orgid   stdate     locid         charnam                                
#>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>         <chr>                                  
#> 1 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01380075 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 2 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01368820 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 3 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01409815 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 4 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01411400 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 5 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrit~
#> 6 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 7 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 8 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01445160 Kjeldahl nitrogen

# Base R
roadsalt_data <- roadsalt_data[, c("orgid", "stdate", "locid", "charnam")]
roadsalt_data[roadsalt_data$stdate >= as.Date("2013-02-04") & roadsalt_data$stdate <= as.Date("2013-02-12") ,]

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#>   orgid   stdate     locid         charnam                                
#>   <chr>   <date>     <chr>         <chr>                                  
#> 1 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01380075 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 2 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01368820 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 3 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01409815 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 4 USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01411400 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), or~
#> 5 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrit~
#> 6 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 7 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570 Phosphorus                             
#> 8 USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01445160 Kjeldahl nitrogen
```

Created on 2018-05-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

==============================================================

If none of these work, there's something else entirely going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you get tired of battling `tidyverse` dependency hell, you could try `data.table` instead:

```
library(data.table)

## Convert to a data.table by reference
setDT(roadsalt_data) 

## Filter on date and only return a subset of columns
roadsalt_data[between(stdate, as.Date("1996-01-01"), as.Date("2015-07-01")), .(orgid,stdate,locid,charnam)]

#       orgid     stdate         locid                                                      charnam
#  1: USGS-NJ 2013-02-19 USGS-01407760 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)
#  2: USGS-NJ 2013-02-19 USGS-01445030 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)
#  3: USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01380075 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)
#  4: USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01368820 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)
#  5: USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01409815 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)
#  6: USGS-NJ 2013-02-12 USGS-01411400 Nitrogen, mixed forms (NH3), (NH4), organic, (NO2) and (NO3)
#  7: USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570                     Inorganic nitrogen (nitrate and nitrite)
#  8: USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570                                                   Phosphorus
#  9: USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01458570                                                   Phosphorus
# 10: USGS-NJ 2013-02-04 USGS-01445160                                            Kjeldahl nitrogen
```